# Question Edit Bug on App

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, android-app

As per the website, any questions which has pending edits are not allowed to be edited, but edit button remains always active in app. It is critical and must be fixed.

Here is a screenshot: (Question which is still pending for an edit review, I clicked on edit, and got the edit window)

> [image: screenshot of a question which is still pending for an edit review, i clicked on edit, and got the edit window.]

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: motorola
- Device Model: Moto G (4)

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (1)

Comment: Because edit button is disabled, and i have more clues if needed, it will long to discuss, you can give it a try.

Comment: I know very surely that the question is pending for an edit review. Hence, edit button is disabled on website for this question. You can download the app and go further to check, you will find edit button active and working.

Comment: As per the website: There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.

Comment: Not a bug, just a missing feature.

Comment: Yes, exactly, title should be improved in [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard)

Comment: No, my name is just fine. If you mean the title of the feature request it's also fine and better than yours.

Comment: O_o Why do you say that @ShadowWizard 's name needs to be improved?